# Switching operands in a binary operation

Tags: binary-operations

I know it is a very simple question and maybe a waste of time, but I wanted to know if there is any mathematical name for the act of changing the order of the operands in a binary operation. That is, going from $a * b$ to $b * a$.

Thanks.

Comment: If things obey the property $a*b=b*a$ then $*$ is called *symmetric*, but nothing comes to my mind off the top of my head as far as a verb form goes. You need to have more confidence in yourself! You want to know the answer, therefore it is *not* a waste of time, since it interests you.

Comment: In the case of groups this is the opposite group $G^{op}$, I think in certain categories, like groups, algebras etc this operation gives an equivalence to the opposite category.